# Android Google Maps V2 shows blurry image on Android 2.3.3 - Titanium

Tags: android, google-maps, titanium, blurry

I have implemented the ti.map module on SDK 3.1. I run this code to show a map:

```
var mapObject = require("ti.map");
var map = mapObject.createView({
    width:Ti.UI.FILL,
    height:Ti.UI.FILL,
    annotations:annotations,
    userLocation:true,
    regionFit:true,
    mapType:mapObject.NORMAL_TYPE
});
```

Here is an image of the blurry map:

http://goo.gl/QKZNv

Which is taken from a device with Android 2.3.3.

It works fine on Android > 4.

I have set up the right google maps v2 key. Because when I didnt have a key, it simply didn't show a map, but only a grey area.

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

I don't if this is answer is a solution to your specific situation.

I had the some problem by using both the Google Maps Android API debug and release keys mixed together. When I ran my app in debug mode using the release key. It shows maps from the cache but will never load it from the Google Maps servers because the key is incorrect. This results, when zooming, in blurry or missing images.

Your app will show an error like the one below on startup:

```
05-13 13:51:22.053: E/Google Maps Android API(29198): Ensure that the following correspond to what is   in the API Console: Package Name: com.<YOUR PACKAGE>, API Key: <KEY>, Certificate Fingerprint:   <FINGERPRINT>
```